# Makemessages throws ImportError on settings

Tags: python, django, internationalization, virtualenv

I need some help with a Django/Python app.
I try for many days to run the "makemessages" command of django-admin without success...

Some explanation :
My project directory tree:

```
MyProject
   MyProject
      locale
      settings.py
      wsgi.py
      ...
   App1
      models.py
      views.py
      ...
```

When I try to run

```
django-admin.py makemessages --all
```

I got this error :

```
(env33) PS C:\DEV\myproject> python ..\env33\Scripts\django-admin.py makemessages --all -v 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\env33\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\DEV\env33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'myproject'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\env33\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "C:\DEV\env33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_comman
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\DEV\env33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\DEV\env33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 263, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "C:\DEV\env33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 109, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\DEV\env33\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\DEV\env33\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\DEV\env33\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'myproject.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named 'myproject'
```

However :

```
(env33) PS C:\DEV\myproject> Get-ChildItem Env:DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Name                    Value
----                    -----
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE          myproject.settings
```

And "C:\dev\myproject" is in the "PATH" environment variable. I tried to run Django shell with :

```
(env33) PS C:\DEV\myproject>python .\manage.py shell
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import myproject.settings
>>> myproject.settings.DEBUG
True
>>>
```

All seems to be OK, and runserver is working as well. As you can see, I'm working in a virtualenv, it could be a problem ?

I also try to run `makemessages` from **MyProject** subdirectory but I got the same error.

I don't understand. I searched all over stackoverflow and many sites and I didn't even find a working solution.

I am working with Django 1.6, Python 3.3 on Windows.

Thanks for your help.

Regards,
M. Choko

Comment: Just copy paste the `django-admin.py` file in the same directory where your manage.py file is, and execute the `makemessages` command again. Any luck?

Comment: Thanks ! It works but... it does not generate any *.po file :(

Comment: `(env33) PS C:\DEV\myproject> python .\django-admin.py makemessages --all -v 3 -e "py,html,txt,js"
examining files with the extensions: .txt, .js and .html`

Comment: `--all` or `-a` flag is only used when you want to update existing language files, as you don't have any, just don't use this flag. Also use `--locale` flag to specify for which language you want django to create message file for e.g. `--locale=de` or multiple `--locale=de,fr`

Comment: Yeah I just try it and it works :) Thank you very much!